# How to actually implement the paging UIScrollView from Apple's example?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, ios, delegation

I found an example of a paging `UIScrollView` in Apple's developer docs and it's just what I want for my application.  I have a main view with a "Help" button that I want to present a view that users can page through to see all the help topics.  The sample is at:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ScrollViewPagingMode/ScrollViewPagingMode.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008179-CH3-SW1

And it works as advertised, but, as with so many of Apple's examples, they do all kinds of code right in the `AppDelegate`.  I have my own `AppDelegate`, but then I have a `NavigationController` with a `RootView` that has this "Help" button on it. I can't seem to get the example code integrated into my own and have it work.  I'm pretty sure I can't put the code they have in their `AppDelegate` in my own, but how to set it up eludes me.

Can someone point me to an example where they do what I'm talking about?

EDIT:  I was able to create a new project and get it to work like Apple's by moving all the `AppDelegate` methods into the `UIViewController` that the template supplied and creating a new `ContentPage` `UIViewController` to hold the content.  It can scroll from page to page, so I think I can insert this code into my other project ok.

I replaced the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` with an equivalent `viewDidLoad` and got rid of the `AppDelegate` stuff dealing with `window` and such.  Then I changed Apple's `initWithPageNumber:` method to refer to my help pages rather than just creating instances of their generic views.

```
- (id)initWithPageNumber:(int)page {
    NSLog(@"--initWithPageNumber:ContentPage");
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"HelpPage%d", page] bundle:nil]) {
        pageNumber = page;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Thanks for the help - sometimes it's good just to have someone tell you it can be done to keep going!

Comment: I have the PageControl sample project in front of me. Looks simple enough. What *exactly* is your question here?

Comment: @Shaggy, I'll post my code in the morning, but I'm confused about how to implement the scrollview from another view as opposed to the appdelegate. What I've done so far is to put all the appdelegate code into a UIViewController subclass and changed the applicationDidFinishLaunching to viewDidLoad. I end up with a blank view. I may have issues with my nibs, but checked them against the sample pretty carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sample code, the `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method sets up the `UIScrollView` (and a `UIPageControl`, but let's ignore that for now) and then "loads" the first two pages. "Loading" a page consists of loading that page's view controller into memory and caching it. It then adds that controller's view as a subview to the `UIScrollView` offset with an appropriate x based on what "page number" it is. You should be able to do all that in your `viewDidLoad`.

If you have a blank view when your view controller's view is shown, then you haven't added the subview correctly to your `UIScrollView`. Depending on what exactly you changed, that could be some combination of (a) not getting the x offset correct, (b) not setting the frame correctly, or (c) not adding it as a subview correctly.

If you post some of your own code we might be able to shed some light on the problem.